# Is there a way to fit two pages on one page in MS Excel when printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, printing

I have a table in Excel. It is 2 pages long, but only half-page wide. Is there a way to print both parts of this table on one page, so one next to another? I don't want to move the data, I would like to know whether this is possible through the printing or page settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something you can try:

(This assumes you're using ISO A4 paper and Office 2007+, but the general idea is sound for other occasions.)

Change the paper size to A5 portrait, select only the columns with data and select Page layout -> Print Area -> Set print area.

In the print pane, change the scaling options to fit all **columns** in one page. Then change printer properties to print the two A5 sheets on one A4.

Comment: Can you explain more the "change the scaling options to fit all columns in one page" ?

Comment: @sakis.a It's the option to fit multiple pages on one sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to [Page Break Preview](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-HP010021539.aspx). If you do not like the designate pages, then move the lines and Excel will print it as you dictate.

If it ends up crunching too much horizontal data, go to the print preview and in the setup switch to landscape mode. The main point is that you can tell excel exactly how to print your cells.

Comment: You can also flip from portrait to landscape (or vice-versa), which would allow more to be on the page after making it into one page using the Page Break Preview.   VERY handy option, useful for compressing output onto fewer pages, or onto a specific page count.

Comment: -1. Doesn't answer the question, specifically it doesn't address how to print `one [page] next to another`. Page Break Preview simply allows you to move the row on which the page breaks.

Comment: @AndiMohr Fair enough. After re-reading the question this is clearly an answer to a different question. Btw, Page Break Preview lets you adjust rows and columns. but wouldn't help the OP with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an amazing Excel function very few people know about. Don't know why it's been kept such a secret but it's a very nifty feature!

**Excel Camera Tool**

To use the Camera tool, you need to customise your toolbars.

In Excel 2007, this looks something like this ([image from Chandoo](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/12/02/excel-camera-tool-help/)):

[image]

In Excel 2010 you can add it to your [Quick Access Toolbar](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/camera-tool-function-in-excel-2010/):

[image]

Select the range you want to appear in the right "column", then click the Camera tool button. The cursor will change to a cross. Now click wherever you want your right "column" to appear.

You should get something like this.

[image]

Position as you like, and remove the border (if you want) by right-clicking the image and selecting `Format Picture`.

Now set your print area to be the left and right columns (excluding the rows below your left column).

**What makes the Camera Tool so Great?**

The wonderful thing about the camera image is that it's not static - if your data changes, the camera image will also change, automatically. It's a great tool!

**Brilliant for complex layouts**

For simple scenarios like this, it may be overkill but if you have several areas you want to display next to each other (especially with different column widths, row heights etc) the Camera tool really comes into its own.

Comment: Just curious to know - how is it different from snipping tool? I'm using Excel 2013 - and it is really difficult to use this _Camera_ tool in Excel

Comment: It's different because the image produced by the Camera tool is not static. If you use the snipping tool and then your data changes, then you'll have to take a new screengrab with the snipping tool. The camera tool however, immediately updates when the data changes. Thanks for asking - I've called this out to draw attention to it in my answer.

Comment: Don't have Excel 2013 so I'm afraid I can't guide you on how to use it there. This might be worth a look though: http://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/msoffice/excel/excel-2013-use-the-camera-tool-to-print-multiple-sheets-on-a-single-page.html

Comment: I do now have Excel 2013 and haven't had any trouble with the camera tool - it's unchanged from the 2010 version. Let me know if you're still having problems @Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people keep saying the same thing, but it isn't the answer you seek. Try this if you are like me and had to figure it out yourself.
Go to the Page Layout tab, if you have the more modern day office. 
Highlight what you want to fit onto 1 page. 
Now look for the tiny arrow just to the right of Page Setup and click it.
Page Setup pops up. Select the option "Fit to: ? page(s) wide by ? tall". In this area, choose 1 each box. 
Click OK.
Now print, and make sure before you ok that it will print onto 1 page.
I had to discover this on my own and had no help, because everywhere I looked, I couldn't find the answer.
Hope this works for you.
SW

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to change the settings in the printer.  Set the area you wish to print in page layout_print area.  Print Preview_Page Setup and choose the Portrait or Landscape mode and fit to pages.  You may have to play with how many pages tall to get the print to a readable size on the print.  Choose Options at the bottom right on the Page Setup dialog box.  My printer has a tab called "Finishing".  Here I can select how many pages per sheet and the page order.  I chose 4 pages per sheet (because it is either 2, 4, 6, etc. and I have 3 pages) and then a page order of Right, then down.  I printed in both portrait and landscape mode to see which was best.  My printer is HP LaserJet Professional M1212nf MFP.

Answer (score 0):

1. printers & scanners --> print server properties --> pick form --> edit paper size --> save form (new name, example name: A4leftside)
2. install wondershare pdf element  (microsoft print to pdf cant detect A4leftside, but wondershare can)
3. print excel table with wondershare printer, set paper type to A4leftside --> dont print yet.
4. change printer wondershare to microsoft print to pdf --> dont edit setting, just print --> save pdf file, etc

my settings:
im creating a form with paper size 1/2 A4 (10.5cm x 29.7 cm)
print pdf
then join pdf combine 2 in 1 free online --> left+right setting --> paper size become A4 (21 x 29.7)