# Fit two pages on one page in MS excel when printing (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In answer to the question [Is there a way to fit two pages on one page in MS Excel when printing?](https://superuser.com/questions/448779/is-there-a-way-to-fit-two-pages-on-one-page-in-ms-excel-when-printing) I have a further question, please.

My Excel page has 15 (fairly narrow) columns left to right, in Arial narrow size 8 there are 77 pages.  We would like to print 30 columns, i.e. two 'pages' A4 (about 127 rows) next to each other.  The moment one selects 2 pages in the print view, it turns the A4 to landscape - we require it in A4 portrait, 30 columns.  I manage to get the columns narrower (by both changing the font & by scaling it) but still cannot find a way to do it 2 pages up on an A4 portrait.  In Word I would have been able to select to 'columns' on the page, then it appears next to each other... maybe I want to do the impossible?

Please can you guide me?

Thank you

Christa

Answer (score 1):

Do you insist on doing this through the print dialog? 
You may be able to get a similar effect by putting the data into the desired arrangement in Excel.

For demonstration purposes, let’s pretend that your file has three columns with 26 data rows
plus one header, like this:

[image: Rows for Al through Zarathustra, abridged]

Now suppose that all your rows are the same height, and that 11 rows
(the header plus ten data rows) fit on a printed page. 
Now, on a separate sheet (or maybe even in a different workbook), enter these formulae:

- `A1` –> `=Sheet1!A1`
- `E1` –> `=Sheet1!A1`
- `A2` –> `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1,ROW()-1+10*INT((ROW()-2)/10),0,1,1)`
- Drag down to `A17`.
- `E2` –> `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1,ROW()-1+10*INT((ROW()-2)/10)+10,0,1,1)`
- Drag down to `E17`.
- Select `A1:A17` and drag over to Column `C`.
- Select `E1:E17` and drag over to Column `G`.

Here’s what you get:

[image: Data folded into two columns]

I leave cleaning up the zeroes at the end as an exercise for the reader. :-)